# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:3)

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and I have an error with my code that I do not understand. I am in the process of building an e-Commerce site with anguar (version 8). the project was almost done when i did an "ng build" to generate the "dist" folder. and it worked very well. But after, the project is not finished, I made some modification to get a final version, but when I do "ng build" now it doesn't work anymore. it generates an error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.regexp.exec.js 1:3
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/core-js/es/regexp/index.js 3:0-39
 @ ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es5-polyfills.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es5-polyfills.js zone.js/dist/zone-legacy ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/jit-polyfills.js ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es5-jit-polyfills.js ./src/polyfills.ts
```

I don't understand what this is for. can someone please help me? Thank you !!

Comment: can provide any sample code? I think this problem has a lot of reason,

Comment: have you checked if the file (I am assuming UTF-8) has a BOM (Byte Order Mark) if so, delete it. also check for non-printable characters in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue every time I restart my PC. I don't know way but I always get over it by deleting the node modules folder and reinstalling them again